# Changing image widths after page had loaded if width is declared already? If width is undeclared, width will change but not if declared as I have

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, classname

The trouble is that I need these images with generated IDs "cam_snap_XXX" to become a different width if they are dragged and dropped into this area. I can make the height change but NOT THE WIDTH because the width is designated to 20px if x==1. Never is the image height specified therefore I believe that is the reason it is changeable? Q: How can I make these image widths change from 20px to 100px if "dragged"?

```
while (cnt <= 100) {
    cam_icon=document.getElementById('cam_snap_' + cnt);
    cam_icon.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if (x==1) { 
        cam_icon.style.width = '20px';
        cam_icon.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

The height changes from the following javascript...

```
//js for adding class "dragged" which gives new height and width image parameters
$('.droparea td.drop').droppable({
  onDrag: function (e, source) {
      $(this).addClass('dragged'); //Changes height correctly not width though.
  }
}
```

And the css..

```
//css for attempting to change image width and height on drop
.dragged{
    height: 100px; //Works because height stretches image height from ~20px to 100px.
    width: 100px; //**Doesn't work and is useless because width remains 20px.**
}
```

Should I try removing the class before adding class 'dragged' to these images? Using removeClass()? Any ideas are welcome even if not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of javascript modifies your HTML

```
cam_icon.style.width = '20px';
cam_icon.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

to

```
<someTag id="cam_snap_x" style="width:20px;visibility:visible">
```

According to css rules inline style (inside an HTML element) has the highest priority. so you'll have to change attribute value to see changes in UI.

Solution 1: change your onDrag function like below.

```
$('.droparea td.drop').droppable({
  onDrag: function (e, source) {
      $(this).width(100).height(100); //This will change the style property
  }
}
```

Solution 2: Use [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) to prioritize value specified in class over inline style attribute

```
.dragged{
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px !important; 
}
```